# UndeliverableException while calling onError of ObservableEmitter in RXjava2

Tags: retrofit2, rx-android, rx-java2

I have a method which creates an emitter like below, there are a problem(maybe it is normal behavior) with calling onError in retrofit callback. I got UndeliverableException when try to call onError.

I can solve this by checking subscriber.isDiposed() by I wonder how can call onError coz i need to notify my UI level.

> > - Addition 1
>
> ```
> --> RxJava2CallAdapterFactoryalready implemented   
> private static Retrofit.Builder builderSwift = new Retrofit.Builder()
>            .baseUrl(URL_SWIFT)
>            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
>            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
>            .addConverterFactory(new ToStringConverterFactory());
>
> --> When i added below code to application class app won't crash
> --> but i get java.lang.exception instead of my custom exception  
>
> RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler(Functions<Throwable>emptyConsumer());
>
> @Override
>     public void onFileUploadError(Throwable e) {
>         Log.d(TAG, "onFileUploadError: " + e.getMessage());
>     }
> ```

```
public Observable<UploadResponseBean> upload(final UploadRequestBean uploadRequestBean, final File file) {
    return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<UploadResponseBean>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(@NonNull final ObservableEmitter<UploadResponseBean> subscriber) throws Exception {

                 // ---> There are no problem with subscriber while calling onError        

                // ---> Retrofit2 service request 
                ftsService.upload(token, uploadRequestBean, body).enqueue(new Callback<UploadResponseBean>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<UploadResponseBean> call, Response<UploadResponseBean> response) {

                        if (response.code() == 200){
                            // --->  calling onNext works properly
                            subscriber.onNext(new UploadResponseBean(response.body().getUrl()));
                        }
                        else{
                            // --->  calling onError throws UndeliverableException
                            subscriber.onError(new NetworkConnectionException(response.message()));                
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
                        subscriber.onError(new NetworkConnectionException(t.getMessage()));
                    }
                });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since version 2.1.1 `tryOnError` is available:

> The emitter API (such as FlowableEmitter, SingleEmitter, etc.) now
>   features a new method, tryOnError that tries to emit the Throwable if
>   the sequence is not cancelled/disposed. Unlike the regular onError, if
>   the downstream is no longer willing to accept events, the method
>   returns false and doesn't signal an UndeliverableException.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/CHANGES.md

Comment: But it still doesn't guarantee that `RxJavaPlugins.onError()` won't get called, see https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/5477

Comment: This is considered experimental and unstable!

Comment: @arekolek they closed this issue, without fixing

Comment: I don't think they can fix it. When I had this issue, I installed my own error handler that suppressed the one specific error I wanted suppressed.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is like you say you need to check if `Subscriber` is already disposed, that's because RxJava2 is more strict regarding errors that been thrown after `Subscriber` already disposed.
RxJava2 deliver this kind of error to `RxJavaPlugins.onError` that by default print to stack trace and calls to thread uncaught exception handler. you can read full explanation [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What%27s-different-in-2.0#error-handling).

Now what's happens here, is that you probably unsubscribed (dispose) from this `Observable` before query was done and error delivered and as such - you get the `UndeliverableException`.

> I wonder how can call onError coz i need to notify my UI level.

as this is happened after your UI been unsubscribed the UI shouldn't care. in normal flow this error should delivered properly.

**Some general points regarding your implementation:**

- the same issue will happen at the `onError` in case you've been unsubscribed before.
- there is no cancellation logic here (that's what causing this problem) so request continue even if `Subscriber` unsubscribed.
- even if you'll implement this logic (using `ObservableEmitter.setCancellable()` / `setDisposable()`) you will still encounter this problem in case you will unsubscribe before request is done - this will cause cancellation and your  `onFailure` logic will call `onError()` and the same issue will happen.
- as you performing an async call via Retrofit the specified subscription `Scheduler` will not make the actual request happen on the `Scheduler` thread but just the subscription. you can use `Observable.fromCallable` and Retrofit blocking call `execute` to gain more control over the actual thread call is happened.

to sum it up -
guarding calls to `onError()` with `ObservableEmitter.isDiposed()` is a good practice in this case.
But I think the best practice is to use Retrofit RxJava call adapter, so you'll get wrapped `Observable` that doing the Retrofit call and already have all this considerations.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i added additional information can you look at that also i am checking this issue but i couldn find a solution https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4863

Comment: I found the problem. There is an error control method in retrofit response and I recognize that I am triggering onError twice, because of I got this exception for the second trigger. As you said, I disposed subscriber before.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that this issue was caused by using incorrect context when retrieving view model in Fragment:

```
ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity(), myViewModelFactory).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

Because of this, the view model lived in context of activity instead of fragment. Changing it to following code fixed the problem.

```
ViewModelProviders.of(this, myViewModelFactory).get(MyViewModel.class);
```