# Why do I get UndeliverableException

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java2, rx-kotlin2

In the android app, the process goes like that: at first, I fetch notes from local SQLite and then make Http calls for each note. I use composite disposable to hold all disposables and release them when activity is destroyed. The code looks something like that:

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    var compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

    override fun onResume(){
        updateDatabaseData()
    }

    fun updateDatabaseData(){
        compositeDisposable.add(
            Observable.fromCallable{
                fetchDataFromDatabase()
            }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .flatMap{
                Observable.fromIterable(it)
            }
            .flatMap{
                getUpdateStateObservable(it) // make remote HTTP call for every note in the list from local DB
            }
            .subscribe()
        )
    }

    fun getUpdateStateObservable(note:Note):UpdatedNote{
        Observable.fromCallable(
             // make HTTP call and build some UpdatedNote
        )
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    }

    fun fetchDataFromDatabase():List<Note>{
        // fetch data from local DB
    }
}
```

And this code worked well until the moment when internet connection is lost. So every time HTTP calls in method `getUpdateStateObservable` is made an error is thrown. And *sometimes* it results in `io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException` pointing at line where network error in `getUpdateStateObservable` happens. And *sometimes it's not*. I've tried to use not a pool of threads but a single one as `Schedulers.single()` when making the HTTP request. And this works well. However, I'd like to process all those requests concurrently to speed them up.

Thanks

Comment: did you checked this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43884764/undeliverableexception-while-calling-onerror-of-observableemitter-in-rxjava2

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. I understand that inside ```getUpdateStateObservable``` every HTTP call results in Exception. The issue is when those Exceptions happen concurrently (see ```subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())```) that results in UndeliverableException. But when i switch to processing requests sequentally  as ```Schedulers.single()``` that works good. Why is that?